# Redirecting input to thread

Tags: c++, fork, dup

I have a really simple code where I fork once and the child node mutates with execlp and the parent keeps doing its work. Nothing too fancy.

What I want is to redirect **all** the standard input to the execlp-ed thread, not the parent.

So if I execute

```
echo "hi" | ./parent.o
```

this can be captured with a `string s; cin >> s;` in `some_command.cpp` (but not in parent.cpp!).

Current situation (parent.cpp):

```
int main()
{
  int pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0) {
    std::cout << "Something crashed" << std::endl;
    exit(-1);    
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    // We are the forked child
    execlp("/some/command", "some_command", NULL);
    std::cout << "Execlp failed" << std::endl;
    exit(127);
  }
  // We are the parent, and we keep running
  // More stuff...
}
```

Right now some_command.cpp contains just an empty `int main() { }`.

Thanks.

Comment: you are confusing thread/process. `fork` creates a new process